# Python 3.9 uninstalled & deleted, yet being prioritized in command line. "fatal error in launcher"

Tags: python, cmd, pip

`py --version shows 3.10`  which was installed manually in Windows, not from cmd

Pip install attempts to run with 3.9, then throws the error:

```
no "\\python39\\python.exe" nor "Scripts\\pip.exe"
```

How do I prioritise running with new version ?

Tried

- Deleted path env. variables and 3.9 launcher, didn't solve.
- up to date: `pip setuptools wheel`,
- forced pip installs

Comment: What does your path look like now (make sure you check in a new terminal window)? What do you mean by "deleted 3.9 launcher"? If you're talking about `py.exe` then a) that should have been in a Windows system folder that you shouldn't modify manually and b) it is, by design, not version-specific. Does `py -m pip` work?

Comment: Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It describes fully the `Path` management on Windows. Please read also the Microsoft documentation page [FAQ's about using Python on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/faqs) with information about `py.exe` and the Python documentation [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do the following:

- Restart computer / environment
- Check start folder to see if you have Python there still
- Run `python3.9` in CMD to see if an exe is still in PATH

---

A quick fix would be to use:

```
pip3.10 install # package here
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebooted your system after modifying the environment variables?
Some applications only detect changes after a full system reboot.